framer-motion gesture animation
i would like to create a framer motion animation in React that removes and element on click and visualizes another element.
Here is an example
example
This is my code:
            {!tileOpen ? (
              <motion.div
                whileHover={{ scale: 1.2 }}
                onClick={handleTrigger}
                className={styles.tile}
            
              >
              </motion.div>
            ) : (
              <motion.div
                animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                transition={{ delay: 0.9, duration: 0.5 }}
                onClick={handleTrigger}
                className={styles.tileOpen}
              >
               <Image
                  src={`/test/test.svg`}
                  alt="testimage"
                  width={116}
                  height={35}
                  
                />
              </motion.div>
            )}

The problem is that in my animation the element does not appear the same way. I am not able to delay the animation.

It would be helpful to include all your code and not just parts of it! Eg. a Codesandbox

  The issue you are facing is the sum of states and framer-motion.
You can't swap a component and animate it in the same time.
You could try to play the handleTrigger after the animation is done.
Then your logic should look like this:
const [tileOpen, setTileOpen] = useState(false);
    const [animatingOut, setAnimatingOut] = useState(false);
    
    const handleTrigger = () => {
        if (!tileOpen) {
            setAnimatingOut(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
            setTileOpen(true);
            setAnimatingOut(false);
        }, 500);
        } else {
            setAnimatingOut(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
            setTileOpen(false);
            setAnimatingOut(false);
        }, 500);
    }
};

this matches the exit duration of your animation (500ms)
And now you can make sure the title isn't swapped until the animation is done:
{!tileOpen && !animatingOut && (
    <motion.div
                    key="closedTile"
                    whileHover={{ scale: 1.2 }}
                    onClick={handleTrigger}
                    className={styles.tile}
                    initial={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                  >
                    {/* Content for the closed tile */}
                  </motion.div>
                )}
                {tileOpen && !animatingOut && (
                  <motion.div
                    key="openTile"
                    onClick={handleTrigger}
                    className={styles.tileOpen}
                    initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 1.2 }}
                    transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                  >
                    <Image
                      src={`/test/test.svg`}
                      alt="testimage"
                      width={116}
                      height={35}
                    />
    </motion.div>
)}

I hope this works for you. I use the same technique and for me this is the one which works.

Is this what you want?
Demo
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import "./styles.css";

const CardReveal: React.FC = () => {
  const [isRevealed, setIsRevealed] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsRevealed((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <motion.div
        onClick={handleToggle}
        className="image-container"
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: isRevealed ? 1 : 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
      >
        <motion.img
          src="https://i.imgur.com/ApagROY.png"
          alt="Background"
          className="revealed-image"
          initial={{ scale: 0.9 }}
          animate={{ scale: isRevealed ? 1 : 0.9 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        />
      </motion.div>
      {!isRevealed && (
        <motion.div
          onClick={handleToggle}
          className="card"
          initial={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
          animate={{ scale: isRevealed ? 0.9 : 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, transition: { duration: 0.125 } }}
          whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
          whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
        >
          <motion.div
            initial={{ scale: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.95 }}
          ></motion.div>
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardReveal;


body {
  background-color: #0d202d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.card-container {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #051523;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.revealed-image {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2f4452;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

